# How to properly query Kafka REST Proxy?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

I'm running a dockerized distribution of Confluent platform:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                             COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
e6963904b485   confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.0.1   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   11 hours ago   Up 11 hours   0.0.0.0:9021->9021/tcp, :::9021->9021/tcp                                              control-center
49ade0e752b4   confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:7.0.1                  "/bin/sh"                11 hours ago   Up 11 hours                                                                                          ksqldb-cli
95b0982c0159   confluentinc/ksqldb-examples:7.0.1                "bash -c 'echo Waiti…"   11 hours ago   Up 11 hours                                                                                          ksql-datagen
e28e3b937f6e   confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:7.0.1               "/etc/confluent/dock…"   11 hours ago   Up 11 hours   0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp, :::8088->8088/tcp                                              ksqldb-server
af92bfb84cb1   confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:7.0.1                  "/etc/confluent/dock…"   11 hours ago   Up 11 hours   0.0.0.0:8082->8082/tcp, :::8082->8082/tcp                                              rest-proxy
318a999e76dc   cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.5.0-6.2.0   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   11 hours ago   Up 11 hours   0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp, :::8083->8083/tcp, 9092/tcp                                    connect
0c299fbda7c5   confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.0.1             "/etc/confluent/dock…"   11 hours ago   Up 11 hours   0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp, :::8081->8081/tcp                                              schema-registry
a33075002386   confluentinc/cp-server:7.0.1                      "/etc/confluent/dock…"   11 hours ago   Up 11 hours   0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp, :::9092->9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9101->9101/tcp, :::9101->9101/tcp   broker
135f832fbccb   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.1                   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   11 hours ago   Up 11 hours   2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, :::2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp                          zookeeper
```

Kafka REST Proxy is running on port 8082

When I issue an HTTP GET call against the REST proxy:

```
curl  --silent -X GET http://10.0.0.253:8082/kafka/clusters/ | jq
```

All I get is:

```
{
  "error_code": 404,
  "message": "HTTP 404 Not Found"
}
```

Given  my configuration, what can I change to actually get some useful information out of Kafka REST Proxy?

Comment: Are you missing a v3? https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html#rest-proxy-v3

Comment: @OneCricketeer - you are correct. I added v3 and that solved the issue. I'd be happy to accept this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just going to vote to close as a typo. Glad that worked, though.